# No result when performing Attribute Transfer Mapping for a line layer to new line layer in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am performing Attribute Transfer Mapping in ArcGIS, but not getting results as desired.

My project is to survey the roads, bridges, culverts and habitation with some attributes by using a GPS device. I deployed my survey team and every week end they send the data in shapefile format, then my in-house team take the survey data reference and extracts the road center line on base images. Now, here the problem arises, when I perform the Transfer Attribute Mapping with matching fields, nothing is working and result is zero.

However, when I use the interactive transfer tool, it's working...

[image]

Can any one suggest me what to do in this situation.

See the below image...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've seen the attribute transfer function not work before.  I then set up a new map document added the data and it worked. Also ensure all data are in the same format and in the same geodatabase - may help.

Comment: I may be misreading your question & information, but if you have only your surveyed data layer selectable when you click with the tool, and then only the extracted data layer selectable when you click again to transfer data, does that work?